# null session in .axd on Azure web site

Tags: session, azure, axd

User is authenticated to the MVC app, but the session becomes null in my .axd call.  The AXD implements IRequireSessionState.  Works locally, just not on Azure.  Ideas?

Comment: Which part of Azure are you using ? Websites or cloud services

Comment: the axd http handler piece is in a web site

Comment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-monitor-websites/#howtoconfigdiagnostics Might be worth setting up some error diagnostics and see if you can see if you a missing an assembly or can get any more information to help you.

Comment: http://blog.degree.no/tag/irequiressessionstate/ Have you seen this also ?